# back back to listing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hello Friends i have a repeater control on which i have binded product and have custom paging on in.when user select on product next page open with all other details of that product. My problem is that when i go to 7 page from paging and then click any product the next page open with details and i want a link on detail page so that i can go back to 7th page on listing

Comment: Do you have a means of going to a particular page on your custom paging?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter in the query string to the detail page that tells the detail page what page the item was found on.  Then in your detail page, you can read in this value and write your link back to the original page with a query string that allows you to go to a specific page in your custom paging.

Comment: can then be any other method for doing this instead of query string

Comment: You could store the information in the session or a cookie as well.